# laravel array of strings to route action

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

A javascript code uses "map" method on array of object to extract just the text value:

```
var checked_leaves = checked_ids.filter(function(elm) {
        if (elm.children.length == 0)
            return elm;     
        }).map(function(elm, index) {
            return elm.text.trim();
        });
```

this array of string is sent to a Laravel route using ajax (with Vue http)

```
this.vm.$http.get(this.el.action + checked_leaves).then((response) => {

        console.log(response);
        //this.vm.speciesDetails = JSON.parse(response.data);

    }, (response) => {

    });
```

Where the this.el.action is api/taxonomytospecies/ and the corresponding Route is:

```
Route::get('api/taxonomytospecies/{ids}', 'TaxonomyController@getSpeciesFromTaxonomy');
```

And inside TaxonomyController:

```
public function getSpeciesFromTaxonomy($ids) {

    // Eloquent job to retrieve the data from the DB
}
```

1) Is there a better way to pass an array of values like the one I get from the javascript code (they are a lot of strings) to a route of a controller?

2) I get an internal 500 error. The error shows that the call is like :

api/taxonomytospecies/name1,name2,name3,name4,name5

But i don't know how to resolve this kind of error

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `post` request instead of `get` as the data is large.

You can send data as an array to the server.

```
var data = {ids: checked_leaves};
```

Then send `data` variable in your `post` request.

In your controller you can get data as:

```
public function getSpeciesFromTaxonomy() {
   $ids = request()->get('ids') // returns an array.

  // Eloquent job to retrieve the data from the DB
}
```

And your route should be as:

```
Route::post('api/taxonomytospecies', 'TaxonomyController@getSpeciesFromTaxonomy');
```

Comment: I tried your solution. If I output a console.log(data) the output is correct; but as soon as i hit the ajax request: this.vm.$http.get(this.el.action + data).then((response) ... the server responds with a 500 internal error. I tried both the solution with POST (taking away the {ids} as a parameter in the Route definiton and the solution with GET. There is already an header for the X-CSRF-TOKEN at the beginning of the Vue file apparently.

Comment: No, it did not.

Comment: Check you `laravel.log` file in the `storage/logs` directory for the possible errors.

Comment: So... I changed $request()->get('ids') to $request->all() and the internal error 500 does not show up anymore (I also set the Reqeust $request as the argument of the function).  If I want to send back my array with : return $ids in th console I get --> status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, body: Array[0].

Comment: So basically I miss something in the controller i guess

Comment: Ok, got it. It was my mistake instead of `$request()->get('ids')` it should be as `request()->get('ids')`. I have updated the answer. But now you are injecting `Request` object in controller so you can use it as `$request->get('ids')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127205/discussion-between-ivan-nn2-and-amit).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the Route as:

```
Route::get('api/taxonomytospecies/', 'TaxonomyController@getSpeciesFromTaxonomy');
```

And the Vue-resource request as:

```
this.vm.$http.get(this.el.action, {params: { ids: checked_leaves } }).then((response) => {
```

but i don't understand why.